Show that $\frac{a^2}{b^2-2b+2024}+ \frac{b^2}{c^2-2c+2024}+ \frac{c^2}{a^2-2a+2024} \geq \frac{3}{2023}$
Let the real numbers $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a+b+c=3$. Show that: $\frac{a^2}{b^2-2b+2024}+ \frac{b^2}{c^2-2c+2024}+ \frac{c^2}{a^2-2a+2024} \geq \frac{3}{2023}$.
My idea: First of all, I thought of using the Bergstrom inequality and I got that:
$\frac{a^2}{b^2-2b+2024}+ \frac{b^2}{c^2-2c+2024}+\frac{c^2}{a^2-2a+2024} \geq \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{a^2-2a+1+b^2-2b+1+c^2-2c+1+2023\cdot 3}= \frac{9}{(a-1)^2+(b-1)^2+(c-1)^2+2023\cdot 3}$
I didn't know what to do going forward. We need to get rid of $(a-1)^2+(b-1)^2+(c-1)^2$ but I don't know how. I thought of the fact that $a^2+1 \geq 2a$.

Function $\dfrac{a^2t}{(b-1)^2+t}$ is increasing for $t>0,$ so it suffices to prove this inequality for any smaller $t$ such as $t=1.$

@dezdichado There is any way of solving it without functions, I didn't learned about them yet. Thanks !

FYI Your approach is already too weak, since $ (a-1)^2  + (b-1)^2 + (c-1)^2 + 2023 \cdot 3 \geq 2023 \cdot 3$, so you can't "go forward" from there.

Note that
$$\frac{2023 a^2}{b^2-2 b+2024}-\frac{2 a^2}{b^2-2 b+3} = \frac{2021 a^2(b-1)^2}{\left(b^2-2 b+2024\right)\left(b^2-2 b+3\right)} \geqslant 0.$$
It remains to prove that
$$\frac{a^2}{b^2-2 b+3}+\frac{b^2}{c^2-2 c+3}+\frac{c^2}{a^2-2 a+3} \geqslant \frac32.$$
From $a+b+c=3$ and $2ca \leqslant c^2+a^2,$ we have
$$\frac{a^2}{b^2-2b+3}=\frac{3a^2}{3b^2-2b(a+b+c)+(a+b+c)^2}=\frac{3a^2}{2b^2+c^2+a^2+2ca} \geqslant \frac{3a^2}{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)}.$$
Therefore
$$\sum \frac{a^2}{b^2-2b+3} \geqslant \frac32\sum \frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2} = \frac32.$$
We are done.

Your solution is elegant and elementary all at once! Considering the equality case in your first estimate alone suffices to conclude that we have equality in the proposed inequality only for $1=a=b=c$.

This proof is for non-negative $a,b,c$ s which probably can be extended with more care. I will use $\sum$ for the cyclic sum:
$$\sum a = a+b+c,\quad  \sum a^2b = a^2b+b^2c+c^2a$$
and so on. First:
$$\dfrac{2023a^2}{(b-1)^2+2023} - \dfrac{a^2}{(b-1)^2+1} = a^2\left(\dfrac{2022(b-1)^2}{((b-1)^2+2023)((b-1)^2+1)}\right)\geq 0.$$ So it suffices to show:
$$S = \sum\dfrac{a^2}{(b-1)^2+1}
\geq 3\quad (1).$$
Use C-S as:
$$\sum\dfrac{a^4}{a^2\left((b-1)^2+1\right)} \sum a^2\left((b-1)^2+1\right)\geq \left(\sum a^2\right)^2\implies$$
$$S\geq\dfrac{\left(\sum a^2\right)^2}{\sum a^2b^2-2\sum a^2b+2\sum a^2}\geq 3\iff$$
$$\left(\sum a^2\right)^2\geq 3\sum a^2b^2 + 6\left(\sum a^2 - \sum a^2b\right) \quad (2).$$
This is where we are basically done. First notice:
$$3\left(\sum a^2 - \sum a^2b\right) = \sum a\sum a^2 - 3\sum a^2b = \sum a^3 -2\sum a^2b+
\sum a^2c = $$
$$=\sum a^3 -2\sum a^2b+
\sum b^2a = \sum a(a-b)^2\geq 0.$$
The rest is just:
$$\left(\sum a^2\right)^2 -  3\sum a^2b^2 = \frac 12\sum (a^2-b^2)^2\geq 0.$$
Moreover, one can potentially use a stronger tool like SOS-Schur to extend this for all reals, not just non-negative. For that, one needs to prove:
$$\sum (a-b)^2((a+b)^2 + 4a(a+b+c))\geq 0$$
but it's been far too long since the olympiad days to remember the details.
